# how to manually install maven plugins, dependencies

Tags: maven, plugins

i have installed Apache Maven 2.2.1, but this server doesn't have internet connection. So maven couldn't install basic plugins. Can i do it manually, could someone tell my how to do it, please.

Comment: Why are you installing such an old version? Maven 3.1.1 is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to do the needed build on a machine which has internet access and transfer the local maven repository later to the target machine.

Or better solution using a repository manager where this machine has access to which solves the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

http://mvnrepository.com/

Go to the MvnRepository, search for the one you need and download the binary. Store it in the appropriate local maven repository directories to be pulled in from there or manually add a reference to wherever you store the .jar

Comment: I would suggest to go to http://search.maven.org (Maven Central) and download the things you need from there.